# How to change user on SWAT page (or how to control Samba by nonprivileged user)

Tags: samba

I logged into SWAT with my nonprivileged user, since the root account is usually disabled on modern Linux systems. I cannot control any Samba parameters by this user. Once I enable the root account, how should I logout from SWAT and re-login into SWAT as root?

Or how should I make my nonprivileged user to be able to control Samba parameters? Put the user into certain group? Specify the user in some SWAT config as a privileged one?

Comment: Okay, I've found how to re-login into the SWAT page - just add another user name in URL, like staff@localhost:901, and during the page reload it will ask another user login/password. However, the second question still stands: how to control Samba by non-privileged user in the scenario where root login is prohibited or where some other user is assigned to maintenance the Samba.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to chgrp/chown the /etc/samba/smb.conf file.. depending on what linux you are using it could be there or a few other places.

I'm still trying to figure out what broke mine, users should be able to reset their own passwords with it!..

> It is even simpler than that for Ubuntu (I’m using 11.04). Just change
>   ownership on the smb.conf file to the user designated as the Samba
>   administrator. For example on my personal machine I am the only use so
>   I am the Samba admin, so …
>
> sudo chown coreigh.coreigh /etc/samba/smb.conf
>
> easy peasy.
>   From: http://missingreadme.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/how-to-get-samba-swat-working-on-ubuntu/